# Error when importing library into Android project

Tags: android

I am trying to use this [cool library here](https://github.com/torryharris/Skycons) in my Android project.

On the github README it says:

> **How to use:**
>
> Import 'SkyconsLibrary' as a library to your project.

I did so by clicking *file/new/import module* and now it is in my Android project. However, when trying to use the library in my project I get these following errors:

**Usage**:

```
<com.thbs.skycons.library.SunView
    android:id="@+id/top_temp_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/time_zone"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/temp_view"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:isStatic = "true"
    app:strokeColor = "#000000"
    app:bgColor = "#ffffff"/>
```

**Error**:

```
Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'isStatic' in package 'com.asus.MyApp'
```

What do I need to do to use the library? I've never imported a library like this, usually I just add the path into my gradle file.

**EDIT:**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher) from AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-43
    is also present at [MyApp:SkyconsLibrary:unspecified] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-29 value=(@null).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-36:19 to override.
```

Comment: Did you add `compile project(':SkyconsLibrary')` to your app's `build.gradle` file? (assuming that your module wound up with the name `SkyconsLibrary`)

Comment: @CommonsWare No I did not, but I just added it, and I got a new error. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a module into your project, that does not automatically add it as a dependency for any other modules in that project. You still need to add a `compile` statement, such as `compile project(':SkyconsLibrary')`, to the module(s) that need the library module that you imported.

> I got a new error. What should I do now?

The error message tells you what to do:

> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-36:19 to override.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your library with this steps:

1. Goto File -> New -> Import Module.
2. Source Directory -> Browse the project path.
3. Specify the Module Name – it is used for internal project reference.
4. Open build.gradle (Module:app) file.
5. Add the following line with your module name in place of “SkyconsLibrary” in the dependencies block:

   compile project(':SkyconsLibrary')
6. After this Android Studio would start saying “gradle files have changed since last project sync”, press the “sync now” link to start a sync.

Thats it. [Reference](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/)